Clarification on How Rvalue Ranges Become Owning Views in C++
I need some clarification:
The reason functions 1 and 2 are considered OK is because when the initial range is an rvalue (either a temporary object or an object marked with std::move()), the constructor moves the range to an internal member of the view, effectively making it an std::ranges::owning_view, am I right? And it has nothing to do with RVO especially in function 1 right? I mean if an rvalue is passed (a temporary range such as a container returned by a function or a container marked
with std::move()), the range is moved into an owning_view, which then holds a range of the passed type with all moved elements directly.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
auto getValues1()
{
    
  return std::vector{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } | std::views::drop(2); // OK
}
auto getValues2()
{
    std::vector col{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } ;
    return std::move(col) | std::views::drop(2); // OK
}
auto getValues3()
{
    std::vector col{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    return col | std::views::drop(2); // // ERROR: return reference to local range
}

int main()
{
    auto res1 = getValues1();
    auto res2 = getValues2();
    auto res3 = getValues3();

}


Unable to replicate in 4 compiler configurations https://godbolt.org/z/K16rrrGcb. Which compiler are you using?

@3CxEZiVlQ I can't reproduce either, but if you enable sanitizer you can see that indeed only case 3 is dangling.

To directly answer your question about "how": the logic for the conversion (and different ways for handling lvalue and rvalue ranges) is in std::ranges::all, which is used in the implementation of most range adaptors.

@WeijunZhou 3CxEZiVlQ I am using MS VS 2022 community edition.

@WeijunZhou where should i enable sanitizer? also the reason function 1 works has nothing to do with RVO right?

RVO is mandatory since C++17. More accurately, the semantics of rvalue has changed in C++17. Since ranges require C++20, it is not an issue for you and it is a moot point to say whether it is related to RVO or not. In other words, cases 1 and 2 are guaranteed to work by the language and not related to what specific optimizations are turned on. As long as you use a standard library that is new enough and uses std::views::all to implement most views, it is guaranteed to work. I'm not familiar with sanitizers with MSVC.

@WeijunZhou Thank you. so mandatory copy elision is the same as RVO introduced in C++17?

@WeijunZhou I just wanted to make sure that what makes those examples work is it RVO and C++20 owning view? or just C++20 owning view?

RVO was an optional optimization by the compiler before C++17, and is no longer relevant because of the new rvalue semantics in C++17. Mandatory copy elision is a term to refer to the phenomenological change compared to earlier C++ standards, but as far as C++17 itself is concerned there is nothing to be copied in the first place. Not "something is copied but the copy is mandatorily elided." That RVO becomes no longer relevant in C++17 can be considered part of the "mandatory copy elision" phenomenon, so they are not the same.

I read your second question again and I think I now get where the confusion is from. The owning_view stores the range in it, not a reference to the range. Whenever the owning_view is moved, the underlying range (in this case, the vector) is moved along with it, so there is no way that the iterators would dangle. If you implement your own views in C++14 and follow the specs from C++20 (except for the concepts), and compile with RVO off, case 1 and 2 will still work. The semantics of owning_view alone is enough to prevent dangling.
